# Quit VIM is slow, usually 2 seconds, it shows

Tags: vim

On quit, vim shows that:

> ".netrwhist" [Not edited] --No lines in buffer--

This process usually takes 2s. How to turn this thing off?

--- Update ---

I noticed that netrw is installed as system-wide. [Use the code below to disable all of those plugins](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/75895).

```
se nolpl
let x = &rtp
se rtp-=$VIMRUNTIME
ru! plugin/**/*.vim
let &rtp = x
unl x
```

Comment: Thanks for following up on how to disable `netrw`. Rather than insert it in your question, it would be best to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to be caused by the vim plugin [netrw.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075).

You could remove the file and, if you do need that functionality, reinstall the plugin.

Comment: To check that nothing is wrong with your installation, run `vim --noplugin` and the problem should go away. Then you know at least one of your plugins is bad (or doesn't play nice together). Disable/uninstall the faulty plugin (netrw.vim in this case) and everything should be OK.